# Datagridview RowValidation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Can you guys help me how to make this happen? I want to have a row validation for adding of items. I have a datagridview named **datagridview1** with columns **dgvTxtItemCode, dgvTxtItemDesc** and so on. I want to add a validation wherein whenever inputted the same itemcode or item desc a message box will appear saying that it has already added.

So here's my code,

```
 Function isAlreadyAdded(itemCode As String, itemName As String) As Boolean
    Dim bFLAG As Boolean
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If r.Cells(0).Value = r.Index = itemCode AndAlso r.Index = itemName Then
            bFLAG = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return bFLAG
End Function



  Private Sub AddDelivery_RowValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowValidating
    With DataGridView1
        If isAlreadyAdded(.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(dgvTxtItemDesc.Name).Value, e.RowIndex) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Item was already added!", "Duplicate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

It's for my capstone so I really need your help. Thankyou guys.

Comment: It says something like 'GNC-SAK-062' which is my itemCode, cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: Why wouldn't you do that on `CellValidating`?

Comment: you mean instead of .rows it will be .cells?

Comment: I mean handling `CellValidating` rather than `RowValidating`.

Comment: can you show me how to do it sir? Please. I really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the cellvalidating event instead of rowvalidating. Like this:

```
Private Sub AddDelivery_RowValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DgOperacionsArticles.CellValidating
    With DataGridView1
        If isAlreadyAdded(.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(dgvTxtItemDesc.Name).Value, e.RowIndex)=True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Item was already added!", "Duplicate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

And also, to make sure this Works, definí the boolean to False by default:

```
Dim bFLAG As Boolean = False
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's not working sir. It say something like my item code cannot be converted to double

Comment: I think you have a problem in this line:     "If r.Cells(0).Value = r.Index = itemCode AndAlso r.Index = itemName Then" You are making a comparsion betwen one object,, one integer and one string... this should fail.